# Why don't I have xlrd?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pip

I installed `pandas` and `matplotlib` using `pip3 install`. I then ran this script:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = pd.ExcelFile("Obes-phys-acti-diet-eng-2014-tab.xls")
print (data.sheet_names)
```

and received this error:

```
dhcp-169-233-172-97:Obesity juliushamilton$ python3 ob.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ob.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = pd.ExcelFile("Obes-phys-acti-diet-eng-2014-tab.xls")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 169, in __init__
    import xlrd  # throw an ImportError if we need to
ImportError: No module named 'xlrd'
```

Why is the necessary `xlrd` missing?

Comment: Funny. I checked and I have xlrd installed. `The following packages will be UPDATED:

    xlrd: 0.9.3-py34_0 <unknown> --> 1.0.0-py34_0`

Answer (score 40):

Install the new module:

```
pip install xlrd
```

Answer (score 22):

"It's an optional dependency [pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/…](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#optional-dependencies) You can install it separately." -- ([bernie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42346/bernie), in a now-deleted commented.)

Comment: I created a community wiki answer in case OP comes back and wants to accept something.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: xlrd in c:\users\user\appdata\local\continuum\
anaconda3\lib\site-packages